# How to set 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE' in wildfly 17 as system property?

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, wildfly, jasper-plugin

Getting this error :
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ViewMsisdnAnswersDetailsPerMNOPerDayMaster.jsp (JBWEB004251: An error occurred at line: 161 column: 98) jsp.error.attribute.nowhitespace

So I tried searching it on google, and found that I need to set 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE'. I have added this property to standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml but didn't work.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 : in Wildfly config file (ie standalone.xml)**

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.2">
    ...
    <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE" value="false"/>
    <system-properties>
```

**Solution 2: in the start command line**

```
$WF_HOME/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone.xml -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false
```